# If $\;\log_m mn + \log_n mn = 49$, find $(\log_m n)^{3/4} + (\log_n m)^{3/4}.$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

Given that $\log_m mn + \log_n mn = 49,\;$ find the value of $$(\log_m n)^{3/4} + (\log_n m)^{3/4}.$$

I have rewritten this expression but have hit a dead end.

Comment: or is the second sumand $$\left(\log_n m\right)^{3/4}$$?

Comment: sorry that was a typo it is supposed to be $(\log_n m)^{3/4}$

Comment: I've corrected your typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit-new answer as original question has been modified
Using simple laws of logarithm, your equation becomes:
$$\log_m  m + \log_m n + \log_n m + \log_n n = 49$$
$$ \log_m n + \log_n m = 47$$

Using $\log_b a = \frac{1}{\log_a b}$,

You can rewrite the above equation as:

$$ \log_m n + \frac{1}{\log_m n} = 47$$

The above is a quadratic which should help you solve $(\log_m n)^\frac{3}{4} + (\log_n m)^\frac{3}{4}$

Not trivial to solve using this method-see Michael Rozenberg's answer.

Answer (score 3):

Let $\sqrt[4]{\log_nm}=x$.  Hence, $x>0$ and  $$ x^4+\frac{1}{x^4}=47 \iff
\left(x^2+\frac{1}{x^2}\right)^2=49$$ 
$$\iff x^2+\frac{1}{x^2}=7$$ 
$$\iff\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)^2=9$$ 
$$\iff x+\frac{1}{x}=3.$$

Thus, $$\left(\log_m n\right)^{3/4} + \left(\log_n m\right)^{3/4}=x^3+\frac{1}{x^3}=\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)^3-3\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)=27-9=18.$$

Answer (score 0):

From the condition we get $$\log_m m+\log_m n+\log_n m+\log_n n=49$$
thus we have $\log_m n+\log_n m=47.\,$ Setting $t=\log_m n$, we get

$t+\frac{1}{t}=47.$

Solving this we get $$t_1={\frac {47}{2}}+21/2\,\sqrt {5}\iff t_2={\frac {47}{2}}-21/2\,\sqrt {5}$$
Can you finish?

---

I'll finish for you: Plugging this in your term we get $$\left( {\frac {47}{2}}+21/2\,\sqrt {5} \right) ^{3/4}+ \left( {\frac 
{47}{2}}-21/2\,\sqrt {5} \right) ^{3/4}=18
$$

Comment: Can _you_ finish it? Factoring $\dfrac{47 \pm 21\sqrt 5} 2$ as a fourth power isn't routine for me even though it's trivial. Michael Rozenberg's answer shows that it's trivial.

Comment: may be but you can also use a calculator to find this result

Comment: A calculator gives a numerical answer, but it might have taken me some work to find an exact answer. Michael Rozenberg's answer does that, and although following the steps is easy, knowing which steps to follow was another matter (which his answer tell us).